# How can I calculate the radius of an n-dimensional hypersphere which touches n vectors and origin?

Tags: vectors

Suppose I have $n$ vectors $\vec x_1,\vec  x_2, ..., \vec x_n$ each of which is n-dimensional.
What would be the radius of the hypersphere that circumscribes all the vectors (as well as the origin)?

I had initially tried to solve this using the logic that, suppose we define a radius vector $\vec r$ then all vectors must satisfy the property that $||\vec r|| =||\vec x_i - \vec r||$ (since both $\vec r$ and $\vec x_i - \vec r$ are radii of the hypersphere. See my crude diagram for justification.)

[image: norm(r) equals norm(x-r)]

$\implies r^Tr=(x_i-r)^T(x_i-r)$

$\implies r^Tr=(x_i^Tx_i) +(r^Tr)-2 \cdot(r^Tx._i) $

$\implies 2\cdot r^Tx_i=x_i^Tx_i$

This gives me n equations and n unknowns as the elements of $\vec r$, but it doesnt give a general mathematical formula to solve for $||\vec r||$

Edit: Could we have a solution for n-dimensional hypersphere in n+1-dimensions, given n vectors that belong to a hyperplane?

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the hypersphere is

$$ (x - x_0)^T (x- x_0) = R^2 $$

where $x_0$ is the center and $x$ can be $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ as well as the origin $\mathbf{0}$.

So we have

$ (x_1 - x_0)^T (x_1 - x_0) = R^2 $

$(x_2 - x_0)^T (x_2 - x_0) = R^2 $

$\vdots$

$ (x_n - x_0)^T (x_n - x_0) = R^2 $

and finally, by substituting $x = \mathbf{0}$,

$ R^2 = x_0^T x_0 $

Substracting the $i$-th equation from the first equation,

$ - 2 (x_1 - x_i)^T x_0 = x_i^T x_i - x_1^T x_1 $ , $i = 2, 3, ...., n $

And the last equation is

$ - 2 (x_1)^T x_0 = - x_1^T x_1  $

Solving this system of equations, we can determine the center $x_0$, then

using $R^2 = x_0^T x_0 $ we find $R$.